# How can I sort this array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to use the `sort()` function to rearrange the array from smallest to largest.

This is my `print_r` of the array which came from serialized data that was imploded:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => 127173
    [1] => 127172
    [2] => 127174
    [3] => 127175
    [4] => 127178
    [5] => 127176
    [6] => 127177
    [7] => 127179
    [8] => 127180
    [9] => 127183
    [10] => 127181
    )
```

With `sort()` and `asort()` I just get a 1 returning.

Comment: please give me your full php code

Comment: You problem is not clear. what is your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code... in fact the `sort` function is working fine.

```
$array = Array
    (
    '0' => 127173,
    '1' => 127172,
    '2' => 127174,
    '3' => 127175,
    '4' => 127178,
    '5' => 127176,
    '6' => 127177,
    '7' => 127179,
    '8' => 127180,
    '9' => 127183,
    '10' => 127181
    );

sort($array); // <= Sort the array desc

foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}
```

> Consider that `sort` function actually **alters** your array and returns **bool**. [See doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

[Check this example online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e953325415897884139fd8c4ef32840cb4fd310)

Comment: I see what happened I had done the following:

$results = sort($results);

That's what kept making it come out at 1.  Doing it just
sort($results);
Worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 0):

Use asort(), like this:

```
$A = Array (127173,127172,127174,127175,127178,127176,127177,127179,127180,127183,127181);
asort($A);
print_r($A);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [1] => 127172 [0] => 127173 [2] => 127174 [3] => 127175 [5] => 127176 [6] => 127177 [4] => 127178 [7] => 127179 [8] => 127180 [10] => 127181 [9] => 127183 )
```

Compare sorting-functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php